# How to put html in a prompt window in google app script

Tags: html, image, google-apps-script, google-sheets, prompt

I'm having fun at work and building a sheet with a bunch of little scripts (read: I'm a debutant that know a little bit appscript and html code). I succeeded to make a script to make a prompt box appear but I would like to add an image in the popup window.

Here's my code so far:

```
function promptbox() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt(
     'Inscrire le No Projet à copier',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
}
```

[I found that post about html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71812259/is-it-possible-to-put-images-in-alerts-in-google-app-script) and try the code as it is and works really well, although, I don't know how to code html in my prompt box. I tried different things, but I didn't succeed.

Is it possible to use html with a prompt box? If yes, how do I code my prompt box with html? If no, is it possible to simply add an image to a prompt box? If yes, how do I code my prompt box with an image? If no, oh well!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to learn how to use HtmlService and SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModeLessDialog() or showModalDialog()

Answer (score 1):

Hy Mole

You **can not** use an HTML output in a prompt.
Please have a look at the Ui class documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui

Check on the methods the class has.

HTML outputs(what you are trying to do) can only work on the following methods

- showModalDialog(HTML, title)
- showModelessDialog(HTML, title)
- showSidebar(HTML)

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought. Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

This will display an html dialog and then when you click display prompt a prompt will appear where you can respond with a value that will be displayed in a toast.

```
function myfunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let body = '<form><input type="text" id="name" name="value" value="Please enter you name." readonly/><br><input type="button" value="Display Prompt" onclick="doStuff()" /></form>';
  let script = 'function doStuff(){ const v = document.getElementById("name").value;google.script.run.alert(v)}'
  let html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><base target="_top"></head><body>${body}<script>${script}</script></body></html>`;
  ui.showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),"Dialog");
}

function alert(v) {
  let r = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt(v);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(r.getResponseText())
}
```

All of the html is embedded in the gs functions as simple strings.

Modeless Dialog:

[image]

Modal Prompt:

[image]